# Powershell script to login with a specific user

Tags: powershell, authentication

I am looking for a script that will help me "lock" a computer with a specific username.

To give an example, John works in a company where every employee can use any computer to login, but John is tired to clean up the mess and leftovers from his colleagues at the office, so, he decided to run a powershell script in **Gpedit.msc** --> **User Configuration** --> **Windows Settings** --> **Scripts (Logon/Logoff)**, or a generic script on the computer to, whenever the computer is rebooted, turned off or, logged off, only his username will ask for credentials. Basically, what I need is to "lock" that computer with a specific user ID, even if it's turned off, rebooted or logged off, only that user ID will show and prompt for password. The computer is always within the network, the user ID does not have administrator rights as the only thing is used on the computer is Internet Explorer to login to a webpage, but my point is the script that I need. A script that enables the "lock" with the specific user ID and a script that disables the "lock", as, I leave on long periods and the place at the computer is free for carnage. And no, I cannot just simply hit Win+Del keys because with a simple reboot, the computer will not remain with the user ID.

Also, I just need the computer to show up with the specific user and **always ask for password**. I do not need to automatically login.

I tried to search on the internet the specific script or some commands that I can play with, but I did not find something. Can someone help me shed some light on this please?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how an actual script would look, but I know you can lock certain users to only be able to log into certain computers (assuming its an AD domain). Does that help at all?

Comment: It helps, to an extent. I would need to ask the AD Admin if he can do that and if this is allowed.

Comment: Tho, the script in powershell should be like a command to tell the windows what user ID should use when starting up. I think it does not really have to be in the network at all.